# Execute ruby method within Javascript - Ruby on Rails App

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, jwplayer

Upon completing watching a video on JWPlayer, I want to execute a ruby method in the UsersController that updates a User model attribute

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

Home.html.erb

```
<script src="//content.jwplatform.com/players/<%= a = Video.mediakey(Time.now.strftime("%Y%m%d").to_i) %>-3sPMNLmx.js"></script>
<script>
jwplayer().on('complete', function() {
  $.ajax("/users/increase_workouts")
});
</script>
```

UsersController

```
# Adds video to number of workouts
    def increase_workouts
      if logged_in?
        current_user.workouts += 1
      else
        redirect_to login_url
      end
    end
```

Routes.rb

> Rails.application.routes.draw do
>
> ```
>   get 'password_resets/new'
>
>   get 'password_resets/edit'
>
>   get 'sessions/new'
>
>   get 'users/new'
>
>   get 'videos/new'
>
>   get 'videos/index'
>
>   root "static_pages#home"
>
>   get 'static_pages/about'
>
>   get 'static_pages/contact'
>
>   get 'static_pages/help'
>
>   get 'signup'  => 'users#new'
>
>   get  'upload' => 'videos#new'
>
>   get    'login'   => 'sessions#new'
>   post   'login'   => 'sessions#create'
>   delete 'logout'  => 'sessions#destroy'
>
>   resources :users do
>   get :increase_workouts, on: :collection 
>   end
>   resources :videos
>   resources :account_activations, only: [:edit]
>   resources :password_resets,     only: [:new, :create, :edit, :update]
> end
> ```

Everything seems to be working, but it is asking for a template... I don't want a template, I want it to increase current_user.workouts by 1.
This is what I get from the server log...

> ActionView::MissingTemplate (Missing template users/increase_workouts,
>   application/increase_workouts with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html,
>   :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :vcf, :png, :jpeg, :gif, :bmp, :tiff,
>   :mpeg, :xml, :rss, :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form,
>   :json, :pdf, :zip], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw,
>   :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates"
>   * "/home/ubuntu/workspace/app/views"   * "/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/app/views"
>   ):   actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/path_set.rb:46:in `find'
>
>   actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/lookup_context.rb:121:in`find'
>   actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:18:in
>   `find_template'   actionview (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:40:in`
>   determine_template'   actionview (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:8:in `render'
>
>   actionview (4.2.2) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in`
>   render_template'   actionview (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'   actionview
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in`_render_template'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in
>   `_render_template'   actionview (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in`render_to_body'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in
>   `render_to_body'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in`render_to_body'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in`
>   render'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block (2 levels)
>   in render'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`block in ms'
>   /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/lib/ruby/2.3.0/benchmark.rb:308:in
>   `realtime'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in`ms'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:44:in `block in
>   render'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:87:in`
>   cleanup_view_runtime'   activerecord (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in
>   `cleanup_view_runtime'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:43:in`render'
>   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render' 
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in`
>   send_action'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in`
>   process_action'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in`call'
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:555:in `block (2
>   levels) in compile'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:505:in`call'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'   activesupport
>   (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in`
>   _run_process_action_callbacks'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in`process_action'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in
>   `process_action'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:32:in`block in
>   process_action'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`instrument'
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `instrument'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in`process_action' 
>   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action' 
>   activerecord (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in`
>   process_action'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'   actionview (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in`process'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal.rb:196:in `dispatch'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in`dispatch'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:237:in `block in
>   action'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:74:in`dispatch'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:43:in `serve'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in`block
>   in serve'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in`serve'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:819:in
>   `call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/head.rb:13:in`call'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
>
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in`
>   call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
>   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in
>   `call'   activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in`
>   call'   activerecord (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:649:in
>   `call'   activerecord (4.2.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in`
>   call'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in`
>   _run_callbacks'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:776:in `_run_call_callbacks'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in`
>   run_callbacks'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in`call'
>   actionpack (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in
>   `call'   web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:18:in`middleware_call'
>   web-console (2.0.0.beta3)
>   lib/action_dispatch/debug_exceptions.rb:13:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in`call'
>   railties (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'   railties
>   (4.2.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`block in call'   activesupport
>   (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
>
>   activesupport (4.2.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in`
>   tagged'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'   railties (4.2.2)
>   lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in`call'   actionpack (4.2.2)
>   lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in`call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'   activesupport (4.2.2)
>   lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in`
>   call'   rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'   actionpack
>   (4.2.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in`call'   rack
>   (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'   railties (4.2.2)
>   lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in`call'   railties (4.2.2)
>   lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'   rack (1.6.4)
>   lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in`call'   puma (3.1.0)
>   lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'   puma (3.1.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:561:in`handle_request'   puma (3.1.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:406:in `process_client'   puma (3.1.0)
>   lib/puma/server.rb:271:in`block in run'   puma (3.1.0)
>   lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:111:in `block in spawn_thread'
>
> Rendered
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/web-console-2.0.0.beta3/lib/action_dispatch/templates/rescues/missing_template.text.erb
>   (1.3ms)

Comment: There's not enough information here to really answer the question, but you can *start* by checking to see your "complete" callback is running. Just stick a `console.log("complete callback");` before your ajax request. You can inspect the response via the `.success` and `.failure` callbacks (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) and look at the rails development logs to see if your request is being sent.

Comment: What other type of information would you like to see?

Comment: I know the "complete" callback is running because I have put alert("Hi!"); before ajax and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It helps to know what you expect it to do and what it is actually doing.

The logs tell us there is an exception being raised: ActionView::MissingTemplate. The "Missing template `users/increase_workouts, application/increase_workouts`" message is telling you something important about a missing view template and it's giving you the locations where it expects to find a template.

When you talk to a controller action by sending a request, it needs to know how to respond to your request. By convention, Rails renders a template with the same name as the action, e.g. `index.html.erb` or `index.jbuilder`, but in the case of your special action, you either need to create a response template or tell the controller what to `render`.

Something like this right after you add one to the workouts in your controller action should give you a "success" response.

`render(json: { message: "Workouts increased" }, status: :ok) and return`

But you can also just `render(status: :ok) and return`. The `:ok` here is a human-friendly way of indicating the HTTP status code 200, which your client (the JS on your page) needs to see in a response.

For more details, see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#using-render

Comment: I did this, and it got rid of the Missing Template. But it doesn't add 1 to workouts. I am unsure why this is the case. Isn't this calling on the method #increase_workouts and if it is adding 1 to current_user.workouts shouldn't that work?

Comment: It shows this in log {Started GET "/users/increase_workouts" for 12.216.140.50 at 2016-08-01 17:32:19 +0000
Processing by UsersController#increase_workouts as */*
  User Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Completed 200 OK in 3ms (Views: 0.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.4ms)}

Comment: Figured it out.. I needed to .save the User.

Comment: Well done! See also ActiveRecord's `update_attribute`. 